# Why is the empty set in the standard topology?

Tags: general-topology

The "standard topology" (put in quotations because I haven't verified that it is in fact a topology yet) is defined by $$\mathcal U \in \mathcal O_\text{standard} \iff \forall p\in \mathcal U \exists r\in \Bbb R^+ : B_r(p)\subseteq \mathcal U$$

Now I'm checking whether this is a topology and I'm getting hung up on the very first property.

If $\emptyset\in \mathcal O_\text{standard}$, then for every $p\in \emptyset$, there exists $\dots$  But there is no $p\in \emptyset$ for us to check the rest of the condition.  So how are we allowed to conclude that $\emptyset \in \mathcal O_\text{standard}$?

Comment: It is true that every $p$ in the empty set has a certain property, for there are no $p$ in the empty set (jargon, the assertion is vacuously true).

Comment: This is an example of a "vacuous quantification". A universally quantified statement over the empty set is usually taken as true by convention.

Comment: So we just define this as a true statement?

Comment: Yes, basically. Similarly, if we said "there exists a $p$ in the empty set such that for all $r > 0$, $B_r(p) \subseteq U$", we would treat that as a false statement. This convention has the benefit that it preserves the property that the negation of a universally quantified statement is existentially quantified, and vice versa.

Comment: Wikipedia: [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To put a different slant what others have said, the statement

"Every $x \in U$ has the property $p(x)$" is equivalent to

"There is no $x\in U$ which lacks the property $p(x)$."

In the case of the empty set $\varnothing$, we are therefore allowed to say that "Every $p\in \varnothing$ has the property that there exists ... etc." because you cannot find an $x\in \varnothing$ which *doesn't* have the property. (In fact, you cannot find any $x\in \varnothing$ at all!)

---

A second informal way to look at it : if every $x\in A$ has property $p(x)$, and every $x\in B$ has property $p(x)$, then intuitively you would want to say that every $x\in A \cap B$ has property $p(x)$. Extending this intuition to the case where $A$ and $B$ have no elements in common $(A\cap B = \varnothing)$ leads us to the idea of vacuous universal quantification.

Comment: Actually,  if every $x\in A$ has property $p(x)$, *or* every $x\in B$ has property $p(x)$, then either way intuitively you would want to say that every $x\in A \cap B$ has property $p(x)$.

Answer (score 8):

This has in fact nothing to do with topology: it is just basic logic. A statement of the form "for all $x$ in $X$, then...", where $X$ is empty, is vacuously true.

Answer (score 3):

You can unbind the quantifiers:

$$ \forall x\in S: P(x) \quad\equiv \quad\forall x: (x \in S) \implies P(x) $$
$$ \exists x\in S: P(x) \quad\equiv \quad\exists x: (x \in S) \wedge P(x) $$

so the formula you wrote means the same thing as

$$ \forall p : p \in \mathcal U \implies \left( \exists r : r \in \Bbb R^+ \wedge B_r(p)\subseteq \mathcal U \right) $$

so the case of $\mathcal{U} = \varnothing$ no longer has you quantifying over an empty domain. And since the antecedent is always false, the conditional is always (vacuously) true.

In fact, we always have

- $\forall x \in \varnothing : P(x)$ is a tautology
- $\exists x \in \varnothing : P(x)$ is a contradiction

---

Some approaches to doing logic actually reject empty domains, and use rules of deduction that only work for nonempty domains, such as:

$$ (\forall x \in \mathcal{D} : P(x)) \implies (\exists x \in \mathcal{D} : P(x)) $$

This should look familiar, as it is quite similar to the objection you had!

However, this implication does not hold without the hypothesis that $\mathcal{D}$ is nonempty. An example of a corrected deduction rule is:

$$ (\forall x \in \mathcal{D} : P(x)) \implies (\mathcal{D} = \varnothing) \vee (\exists x \in \mathcal{D} : P(x)) $$

So keep this in mind — the rules of logic you have learned, be it formally or informally, may actually be *wrong* for the case where empty domains of quantification are allowed, so until you are used to the more general case, always treat such possibilities with care.